# Limma model for incomplete factorial design

Tags: r, linear-model

Currently, I'm trying to design an appropriate model for some gene expression data, to analyse it using `limma`. I've got a few questions regarding model design though. Let's assume that we've got the following data (stored in `pData`):

```
Sample  Treatment   Incubated
1       Naive           No
2       Naive           No
3       IFN             Yes
4       LPS             Yes
5       Naive           Yes
6       Naive           No
7       Naive           Yes
8       IFN             Yes
9       LPS             Yes
```

I'm thinking about the following model:

```
mod = model.matrix(~pData$Treatment+pData$Incubated, data=pData),
```

however, I'm not sure if it is going to work as intended.

1. This is not a proper factorial design, since not every combination of conditions is observed. Is it possible to separate the effects of incubation and IFN (LPS) for such data? Is this model going to cut it?

   `Treatment` is a factor with levels `"Naive", "IFN", "LPS"`. `Incubated` is a factor with levels `"No", "Yes"`.

   Default column names of the design matrix (`mod`) are as follows: `(Intercept)`, `pData$TreatmentIFN`, `pData$TreatmentLPS`, `pData$IncubatedYes`.

   I can interpret the intercept, for each gene, as an average expression in naive and not incubated samples.
2. How do I interpret, for example, `pData$TreatmentIFN`? Is it an average IFN effect in reference to naive samples in general (that is, both naive-incubated and naive-not-incubated)? Or is it an average IFN effect in reference to the intercept (naive-not-incubated) only?

Comment: Can you set up contrasts in limma?

Comment: @Nik Tuzov: Yes.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you merge the two factors into one, with levels like "LPS_Yes", "Naive_Yes", etc, and specify some contrasts wrt the levels of the new factor. That will clarify what you can and cannot "separate".

Comment: @Nik Tuzov: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try.